# Java Date Formatter

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am getting date format as `"YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm"` as formatter object.

How can I format the input formatter object to get only `"YYYY-mm-dd";`?

Comment: You should accept one of the answers below as the solution of your problem, or update your question if you still have no answer.

Comment: For new readers to the question I recommend you **don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`** and also not `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 25):

> I am getting date format as
>   "YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm" as formatter
>   object. How can i format the input
>   formatter object to get only
>   "YYYY-mm-dd";

You can not have date as ***YYYY-mm-dd*** it should be ***yyyy-MM-dd***. To get date in yyyy-MM-dd following is the code:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String formattedDate = formatter.format(todaysDate);
```

Comment: Take care that the `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread safe and is a common source of errors. Use the `DateTimeFormatter` instead

Answer (score 6):

```
Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
        Date date;
        try {
            date = (Date)((DateFormat) formatter).parse("2011-04-13 05:00");
            formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String s = formatter.format(date);
            System.out.println(s);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `SimpleDateFormat`

```
String myDateString = "2009-04-22 15:51";

SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
SimpleDateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

System.out.println(outFormat.format(inFormat.parse(myDateString)));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting a date in the format `"YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm"` and you want it as `"YYYY-mm-dd"` I suggest you just use `inputDate.substring(0, 10)`.

In either way, beware of potential [Y10k bugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_10,000_problem) :)

Answer (score 1):

Following sample formate date as yyyy-MM-dd in Java

```
Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("Now: "+formatter.format(now.getTime()) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, SimpleDateFormat is what you are looking for
http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/jdk/jdk-api-localizations/jdk-api-zh-cn/builds/latest/html/en/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

[`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String formattedDate = formatter.format(todaysDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
Date date=new Date();

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

String formattedDate = formatter.format(date);

System.out.println("formatted time==>" + formattedDate);

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers such as the [one by user2663609](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20696876/642706) are correct.

As an alternative, the third-part open-source replacement for the java.util.Date/Calendar classes, [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), includes a built-in format for your needs.

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

String stringIn = "2011-04-07";

// Returns a formatter for a full date as four digit year, two digit month of year, and two digit day of month (yyyy-MM-dd).
DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.date().withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/London" ) ).withLocale( Locale.UK );
DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime( stringIn ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
String stringOut = formatter.print( dateTime );
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime.toString() );
System.out.println( "stringOut: " + stringOut );
```

When run…

```
dateTime: 2011-04-07T00:00:00.000+01:00
stringOut: 2011-04-07
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has so many good answers !! , here comes another one more generic solution

```
public static String getDateInFormate(String oldFormate , String newFormate , String dateToParse){
    //old "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"
    //new yyyy-MM-dd
    //dateTopars 2011-04-13 05:00  
    String formatedDate="";
    Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat();
    Date date;
    try {
        date = (Date)((DateFormat) formatter).parse(dateToParse);
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(newFormate);
        formatedDate = formatter.format(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return formatedDate;    
}
```

Comment: This question has so many bad answers. About all of them endorsing `SimpleDateFormat`, a notorious troublemaker of a class that we sort of had to use when the question was asked in 2011 but that no one should be using anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                String strDate = entry_date;
                System.out.println("strDate*************"+strDate);
                Date date = null;
                try {
                    date = sdf.parse(strDate);

                } catch (ParseException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

                Date yesterday =subtractDay( date);
                String requiredDate = df.format(yesterday);
                System.out.println("110 days before*******************"+requiredDate);

public static Date subtractDay(Date date) {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -110);`enter code here`
        return cal.getTime();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work.

For parsing input define a formatter:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm", Locale.ROOT);
```

Parse:

```
    String input = "2019-01-21 23:45";
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(input, FORMATTER);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Output so far:

> 2019-01-21T23:45

Format output:

```
    String output = dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
    System.out.println(output);
```

> 2019-01-21

### Tutorial link

[Trail: Date Time (The Java™ Tutorials)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.