# How to format a date from yyyy-MM-dd to yyMMdd

Tags: java

```
    String s;
    Format formatter;
    Date date = new Date();

    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd");
    java.util.Date date1 = ((DateFormat) formatter).parse(birthDate);
    s = formatter.format(date1);
```

to format a date from yyyy-MM-dd to yyMMdd, but its not working. Please help.

Comment: Check this samples : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580965/java-date-formatter

Comment: what does it mean " its not working"??? Does it throw an error, or returns wrong result or doesn't do nothing????

Comment: i do'nt see whats the difficulty with it. You need String. You already have year, month, and dat. It just a simple string manipulation.

Comment: Why do you expect the same format to work for both?

Comment: What is the `birthDate` value ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
    String s;
    DateFormat formatter;        

    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date1 = formatter.parse("2013-07-17");
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd");
    s = formatter.format(date1);
    System.out.println(s);
```