# Parsing SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java

I have this date that I seem to be unable to parse correctly.

String text "Wed May 21 05:44:09 -0700 2014";

This is my date format

```
public static final String DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy";
```

I am trying to use a SimpleDateFormat to parse it.

Error string is unparsable.

What am I doing wrong here.

Note that this is not a duplicate. The solution with forcing locale is not described in the other question.

Comment: *What am I doing wrong here.* You haven't mentioned what your exact problem is, and haven't posted the relevant code along with the error message.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580965/java-date-formatter look here for how to use a date frrmater

Comment: How you use it? Because in ideone it seems to work ok.

Comment: I re-opened as this Question (a) is about date-time not date-only, and (b) is about Locale, unaddressed by the linked Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse your date you can use

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN);
Date parsedDate = sdf.parse("Wed May 21 05:44:09 -0700 2014");
```

But if that fails and you are seeing

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed May 21 05:44:09 -0700 2014"

then most probably `Wed` is not recognised by your default locale as correct day. In that case you will have to set locale to place where this word is recognized, like

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN, Locale.US);
//                                                               ^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: It was the locale that was missing from the parsing.

Comment: Glad I could help, but next time please be more specific about problem you are having. If you see Exception post its stacktrace to let us know which problem we are solving.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.parse ( 
    "Wed May 21 05:44:09 -0700 2014" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z uuuu" , Locale.US ) 
)
```

## Details

The [Answer by Pshemo](http://%22Wed%20May%2021%2005:44:09%20-0700%202014%22) seems to be correct, specify a [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to match the data input. But the Question and Answer both use troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

By the way, your input string is in a terrible format. When serializing date-time values to text, use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats.

## Using java.time

First define a formatting pattern to match your input string.

Specify a [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine (a) the human language for translation of name of day, name of month, and such, and (b) the cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, and such. If omitted, your JVM’s current default locale is implicitly used. Better to be specify explicitly.

```
String input = "Wed May 21 05:44:09 -0700 2014";

Locale locale = Locale.US;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z uuuu" , locale );
```

Parse as an [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html). If we had a time zone we would parse as a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). But we have only an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) of `-0700` in your input string.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse ( input , f );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "input: " + input );
System.out.println ( "odt: " + odt );
```

When run.

> input: Wed May 21 05:44:09 -0700 2014
>
> odt: 2014-05-21T05:44:09-07:00

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), andfz [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).