# Why is my String variable "unparseable" to Date through SimpleDateFormat?

Tags: java, android, date, parsing

I'm trying to parse a `String` value in the format `Sat Dec 03 20:30:33 GMT+00:00 2016` to a `Date` variable, but I'm getting an `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sat Dec 03 20:30:33 GMT+00:00 2016" (at offset 0)` exception. What am I doing wrong here?

```
Date itemDate = new Date();
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss");
        try {
            itemDate = df.parse(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ArticlesContract.ArticleEntry.COLUMN_NAME_DATE)));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: First of all, what is your current locale? Second, where are you parsing the end of the String, which is `GMT+00:00 2016`?

Comment: @Tunaki To be honest I'm not sure, but I think it is pt_PT for the locale. As for the end of the String, is that relevant to this error? I wasn't sure of how to parse that part, so I left it for later.

Comment: No that second part will be your next error. The current error is that `Sat` cannot be understood as a portuguese day of week. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/23790945/1743880, you need to change the locale used by the formatter.

Answer (score 1):

this works

```
    private static void test1() {
            Date itemDate = new Date();
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
            try {
                itemDate = df.parse("Sat Dec 03 20:30:33");
//"Sat Dec 03 20:30:33 GMT+00:00 2016" works too.
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(itemDate);
        }
```

the problem is about 'Dec' month. You have got another locale in your device

Answer (score 0):

**Sat Dec 03 20:30:33 GMT+00:00 2016**

is a string with some locale dependent elements like "Sat" and "Dec"

therefore you have to do:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

then be sure the pattern you are using is matching the string you want to parse...

in your example we see this : "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss"
but the string to parse has for example the year to... so you need to parse that info as well adding in the correct place the year component **yyyy**