# Convert timestamp from one format to another

Tags: java

I have the timestamp as `2015-02-12T12:47:17.101+05:30`. In java, I just wanted to get MMM_dd_yyyy. I tried with SimpleDateFormat class. But i am unable to get it. Could you please tell me how to get month , day and year?
**UPDATE:**

```
public static void main(String[] a ) {
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM_dd_yyyy");
 System.out.println(sdf.format("2015-02-12T12:47:17.101+05:30"));
}
```

I am getting an error as java.lang.IllegalArgumentException. What could be the issue?

Comment: use Regex to parse it

Comment: Well what *exactly* did you try with `SimpleDateFormat`? If you've started off with a string, you'll need one `SimpleDateFormat` to parse, and one to format...

Comment: @TwelveDollar: No, that's a terrible idea. There are perfectly good classes to parse dates - a fully-validating regex would be much, much more complicated than using a class specifically designed for the job.

Comment: @JonSkeet: true in this case

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Date Formatter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580965/java-date-formatter)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `SimpleDateFormat` only formats Dates and Timestamps.  You're passing it a `String`.

To do this correctly, first parse the string you have, into a Date.  Then use your formatter to format it.

```
//Java 7 and above
try {
  SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSX");
  Date date
  date = inputFormat.parse("2015-02-12T12:47:17.101+05:30");
  SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM_dd_yyyy");
  System.out.println(outputFormat.format(date));
}catch(Exception e){
  //cannot happen in this example
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SimpleDateFormat like this:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{

    // This is how to get today's date in Java
    Date today = new Date();

    //formatting date in Java using SimpleDateFormat
    SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("MM_dd_yyyy");
    String date = DATE_FORMAT.format(today);
    System.out.println("Today in MM_dd_yyyy format : " + date);

}
```

According to [this example](http://java67.blogspot.ch/2013/01/how-to-format-date-in-java-simpledateformat-example.html)

Comment: giving IllegalArgumentException when I pass timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public static void main(String[] a) {
    Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm");
    String text = dateFormat.format(timestamp);

    System.out.println(text);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with the following code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM_dd_yyyy");
sdf.format(yourTimestamp);
```