# Saving Date and Time to Firebase for Attendance App. How to Structure Data?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, structure

I'm making an attendance app with time in and time out. What would be the best way to structure the data so that when I generate the attendance report I can set the date range, example date picker1: 9/1/2017 and date picker2: 9/7/2017 and I can get the time in and time out within those days?

```
Date        Time In    Break Start     Break Finish     Time Out    
9/1/2017    8:00 AM    12:00 PM        1:00 PM          5:00 PM 
9/2/2017    8:00 AM    12:15 PM        1:00 PM          6:00 PM 
.
.
9/7/2017    8:00 AM    12:00 PM        1:00 PM          5:10 PM
```

I would like to know how to structure my Firebase database, saving date and time, so that it would be easier to extract all values from specific dates.

Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

database easily to be managed like

```
parentNode
   ----Students / Teachers / Staff 
        ----StudentID /TeachersID /StaffMemberID
           ---Details
                --Name
                --Class / Roll No. /Any details 
           ---Attendance
                --Date in timestamp Format 
                    --Time in : Time in TimeStamp
                    --TimeOut : Time in TimeStamp
                    --BreakTime : Time in Timestamp
                    --BreakFinish : Time in Timestamp
```

Comment: Hello iOS Geek, thanks for your reply. Sorry, I am really new to working with dates in iOS and Firebase. May I know what is a timestamp format? Thanks

Comment: Because i tried to save a date like 2017-09-22 as key but it got separated by 3 nodes, node 22, node 09 and node 2017

Comment: yourDate.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000 this will result in timestamp, Actually its good to store timestamp in Firebase DB. use that line

Comment: Welcome Happy to help

Answer (score 2):

You can structure the database Date-Wise. [Here's the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eFBc.png)

While storing you'll have to convert the date to SimpleDateFormat so you'll get all the values with "AM" & "PM". 
[Click Here For SimpleDateFormat Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580965/java-date-formatter)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Supradip. I will try this structure.

Comment: If you use 2017/09/22 then it will store each '/' as a child. Use 2017-09-22 for correct result (Refer the SimpleDateFormat). If the answer helped you please accept it.